# PHP Sort the multi array and create a new one

Tags: php, arrays

I have such a multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-22
            [triger] => triger1
            [count] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-11
            [triger] => triger2
            [count] => 16
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-15
            [triger] => triger2
            [count] => 8
        )

)
```

I would like each trigger key to create a separate subarray containing all the data for the given key.I would like to sort it and from the result create a new look like this:

```
Array
(
    [triger1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                 (
                    [date] => 2017-11-22
                    [triger] => triger1
                    [count] => 6
                  )
        )
    [triger2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                 (
                    [date] => 2017-11-11
                    [triger] => triger2
                    [count] => 16
                  )
            [1] => Array
                 (
                    [date] => 2017-11-15
                    [triger] => triger2
                    [count] => 8
                  )
        )
)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A `foreach` loop will do

```
$output = [];                                // Output array
foreach ($array as $value) {                 // Loop to array
    if (!isset($output[$value['triger']])) { // Check if triger key exist
        $output[$value['triger']] = [];      // create array with triger key if not
    }
    $output[$value['triger']][] = $value;    // Push value array to triger key
}

print_r($output);                            // Print output
```